# Strange behavior of ggplot's geom_polygon when using gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gganimate

Say that I have these data. One for shading counties of a state and the other for plotting points.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
devtools::install_github("UrbanInstitute/urbnmapr")
library(urbanmapr)

#1. counties dataset for the shading of the background
data(counties)
#keep only Texas counties
counties <- filter(counties, state_fips==48)

#2. dots dataset for dots over time
dots <- data.frame(group = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3)), 
                    lat = c(rep(32, 3), rep(33, 3)),
                    long = c(rep(-100, 3), rep(-99,3)), 
                    year = c(1:3, 1:3))
```

I then plot them (first not using `gganimate`):

```
ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = counties, aes(long, lat, group = county_fips, fill = as.numeric(county_fips))) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "navy", high = "lightskyblue3")   +   
    geom_point(data = dots, aes(long, lat, group=interaction(long, lat), color=year), 
               size=6, show.legend = FALSE) + 
    theme_bw() +
    scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "yellow", "darkgreen")) +
    coord_map() +
    labs(subtitle = paste('Year: {frame_time}')) +  
    theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.8, vjust=-10, size=30)) +  
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white')) +
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank())+
    theme(legend.position = c(0.15, .15)) +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(2,"line"),legend.title=element_text(size=16), 
          legend.text=element_text(size=14))    +
    labs(fill = "abc")
```

Here is the result:

[image]

The problem comes in when I try to animate the dots using `gganimate`:

```
map <- ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = counties, aes(long, lat, group = county_fips, fill = as.numeric(county_fips))) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "navy", high = "lightskyblue3")   +
    geom_point(data = dots, aes(long, lat, group=interaction(long, lat), color=year), 
               size=6, show.legend = FALSE) + 
    theme_bw() +
    scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "yellow", "darkgreen")) +
    coord_map() +
    labs(subtitle = paste('Year: {frame_time}')) +  
    theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.8, vjust=-10, size=30)) +  
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white')) +
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank())+
    theme(legend.position = c(0.15, .15)) +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(2,"line"),legend.title=element_text(size=16), 
          legend.text=element_text(size=14))    +
    labs(fill = "abc") +    
    transition_time(year) +
    shadow_mark(size=6)     

anim_save("output/test.gif", map, end_pause=6, width = 800, height = 800, duration=8)
```

Note that it is exactly the same except for the `transition_time` and `shadow_mark` lines. Here is the result:

[image]

The background colors are VERY different. It might be the case that the colors are reversed or something; I am not sure. However, in my real example using many more dots and different values for the shading, the shading *has little if any resemblance* to the actual data. What in the world is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: What package is the `counties` dataset from? Perhaps `library(noncensus)`?

Comment: The `counties` dataset is from `urbnmapr` from Urban Institute. I apologize for not including this in the code; I have updated it. I am not sure if `noncensus` containts the same dataset or not.

Comment: This looks a lot like a bug. I saw you also filed an [issue report](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/355). Until it is solved, you could consider to build the animation yourself. In the end what `gganimate` is doing is basically rendering a plot for each frame and then combining them using [gifsky](https://gif.ski/) or another renderer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly the problem is, but polygons can be problematic, because they tend to violate the tidy data rule of "one row per observation". Also, as a general principle, I would recommend using `geom_sf()` whenever you're working with geospatial data. Below is code that reproduces your animation using `geom_sf()`.

In theory, I should have been able to plot the points with `geom_sf()` as well, but I ran into another issue that looks like a bug with gganimate, so I had to work around and extract the projected coordinates for the points and plot with `geom_point()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.7.2, GDAL 2.4.2, PROJ 5.2.0

# 1. get shape files for texas
library(tidycensus)
options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)

# download counties for Texas
counties <- get_acs(
  state = 48, # omit to download all US counties
  geography = "county", year = 2015, geometry = TRUE,
  variables = "B19013_001" # need to specify some variable to download, here median income
)
#> Getting data from the 2011-2015 5-year ACS

# 2. dots dataset for dots over time
dots <- data.frame(
  group = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3)), 
  lat = c(rep(32, 3), rep(33, 3)),
  long = c(rep(-100, 3), rep(-99,3)), 
  year = c(1:3, 1:3)
)

# add geometry column
dots_sf <- dots %>%
  mutate(
    geometry = st_sfc(
      map2(lat, long, function(lat, long) st_point(x = c(long, lat))),
      crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
    ) %>%
      st_transform(crs = 3083) # CRS appropriate for Texas, https://epsg.io/3083
  ) %>%
  st_as_sf()

# and extract transformed coords
dots_sf_transf <- dots_sf %>%
  mutate(
    long_transf = map_dbl(geometry, function(x) x[[1]]),
    lat_transf = map_dbl(geometry, function(x) x[[2]])
  )


# 3. static plot
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = counties, aes(fill = as.numeric(GEOID))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "navy", high = "lightskyblue3")   +   
  geom_point(
    data = dots_sf_transf, 
    aes(x = long_transf, y = lat_transf, group = group, color = year),
    size = 6, show.legend = FALSE
  ) + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "yellow", "darkgreen")) +
  coord_sf(crs = 3083) +
  labs(subtitle = "Year: {frame_time}", fill = "abc") +  
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.15, .15))
p
```

[image]

```r
# animation
p + transition_time(year) + shadow_mark(size=12)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Wow, this was an amazing answer. Thank you!